# Сохранение файла от имени пользователя C#

Tags: c#, файлы, права

Вопрос:
Можно ли сохранить файл в сетевую директорию используя учетную запись другого пользователя?

Подробности:
Есть служба, работающая под учетно записью System.
Служба, кроме прочего, занимается синхронизацией со сторонним сервисом из которого нужно выкачивать файлы и складывать в сетевую папку.
Но у System нет прав доступа к сетевой папке.
Зато служба знает логин/пароль пользователя, у которого такие права есть.

(Пока видится только сохранение файла в temp и запуск копирования через `Process.Start`, но может быть есть что-то более элегантное?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы можете выполнить код внутри своего процесса от другого пользователя. Сначала импортируем WinAPI функцию `LogonUser`:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(
    string lpszUsername,
    string lpszDomain,
    string lpszPassword,
    int dwLogonType,
    int dwLogonProvider,
    out IntPtr phToken);
```

А дальше вот так:

```
IntPtr token;
if (LogonUser("SomeUser", "SomeDomain", "SomePwd", 2, 0, out token))
{
    var identity = new WindowsIdentity(token);
    using (identity.Impersonate())
    {
        // здесь вы можете убедиться, что код выполняется под другим юзером
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.UserName);
        // делаем что-то
        File.WriteAllText(@"path.txt", "hello!");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid credentials");
}
```